# we're trying to figure it out as we're going

Tags: grammar, present-continuous, present-simple

Let's say you need to get to some destination, but you don't know the exact route to that destination. I've sometimes heard people say

> we're trying to figure it out as we go

Why is present simple used to say "we go", instead of present continuos "we're going"? Wouldn't it be more correct to say:

> we're trying to figure it out as we're going

because it is said about the specific time, it is not meant "we go" in general?

Answer (score 1):

No, is the simple answer.

The conventional construction is **to do this as we do that**, not "as we are doing that".

So you will hear expressions such as:
**sing as we work**
**listen as the birds call**
**take care as you climb**
**think as you proceed**

It would be correct to say **as you are doing** whatever** but it is not idiomatic. People don't talk like that.

Comment: Thanks, but all your examples are using present simple for both "do this" and "do that". My question is about the phrase which begins with using the present continuous tense "we're trying to figure it out", but ends using the simple present tense "as we go". This is what the question is about.